# Infinitesimal length in the cylindrical system

Tags: vector-analysis

I understand how to use the distance formula to arrive at this:

"An infinitesimal length in the rectangular system is given by
$dL^2= dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ ."

How do you prove the following?

"In the cylindrical system the corresponding quantities are
$dL^2= dr^2+r^2dφ^2+dz^2$ ."

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to put $$dL^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2\\dL^2=dr^2+r^2dφ^2+dz^2$$
For your proof, in a cylindrical coordinate system
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2\\x=rcos(φ)\\y=rsin(φ)\\z=z
$$
and because of product rule
$$
\\dx=d(rcos(φ))=dr*cos(φ)+r*d(cos(φ))
$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dφ}cos(φ)=-sin(φ)\\d(cos(φ))=-sin(φ)dφ$$
it follows that
$$\\dx=cos(φ)dr-rsin(φ)dφ
$$

and just substitute that for dx and find what dy is in terms of r and φ.

The expression $$d(f(x)g(x))=f(x)*dg(x)+g(x)*df(x)$$

is just the product rule. If you multiply both sides of the equation by 1/dx then it looks much more familiar.

Comment: Yes, I edited and corrected the equations. Thanks.